# What happens when a photon impinges not in the space charge region?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, photoelectric-effect

What is the result when a photon doesn't hit the pn-junction? Can't it be lifted? From my understanding there should be valence and conductance bands everywhere across the material. Nevertheless, I'm quite certain the effect will be different when lifting an electron within the scr region and in case not?

[image]

source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/14-p-n-junction-photodiode-70_fig6_334710952

Comment: Sure, it makes e-h pairs, but unless it is in or close to the junction the charges will not get separated by the built-in field, so will not register as current external to the device.

Comment: does this change when there is an external electric field?